# Thrift C++ client and Java server two way SSL

Tags: java, c++, ssl, thrift

I am trying to setup a two way SSL connection in between thrift C++ client and thrift Java server. Since I am  new to thrift and client server connections, can someone help me with it?

Currently the part I am stuck at is that I am generating the .pem files for the key and certificate. I can use them directly for the thrift C++ client but how can I use it for in thrift Java server? As far as I know the thrift Java server supports the .jks format keystore and trust stores along with the password/key.
It will be great if someone who already have done something like that can provide me a sample working implementation for thrift C++ client two way SSL connection with the thrift Java server.

Comment: It has been resolved. Thanks for the concern..

Comment: I am trying to solve the same problem in reverse (c++ server -> java client) and I am stuck on the same issue.  Can you please tell me about your resolution?